# How do I use modules in Django?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm trying to display a graph on a web page. I can get the graph to show up with a simple example that only uses functions defined within the function. However, I want to be able to expand it further. In my original code, I have one main 'graphing' function that uses the functions of other modules so that it stays organized. When I try to import these modules, which exist as files within the Django app folder, it says there is no module with that name. How do I fix this?

```
Error: File "/Users/andrewho/Desktop/website/charts/views.py", line 48, in <module>
    import graphing
ImportError: No module named 'graphing'
```

I clearly have a file in the app folder called graphing.py, so why does it give me this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use " from 'where' import 'what'"

so may be like "from . import graphing" if its in the same directory